# What are these containers called?

Tags: product-recommendation

I'm looking for a certain type of plastic container (around 2-3 gallons) that has a spigot on the bottom and allows you to drain liquid using gravity. I used to see them a lot in the Navy used for cleaning fluids but can't figure out what to search for to find them.

I'm ultimately looking for something I can put liquid into and attach surgical tubing to the "drain" or "spigot" and has an on/off valve.

Does anyone know what these are called or where I can find them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know you can get them from Uline, they call them [Carboys](http://www.uline.com/BL_8169/Carboys).

[image: Uline Carboy]

<s>I'm not sure if this is a standard name for a jug with a spigot, googling for carboy would lead me to believe it is not.</s> As [Jacob S](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/13473/jacob-s) pointed out, these are sometimes called a "rectangular carboy"

There is a similar product at The Container Store, they call them [Slimline Fridge Jugs](http://www.containerstore.com/shop/kitchen/refrigeratorFreezer?productId=10006448)

Comment: Awesome! That's what I was looking for!

Comment: sometimes called a "rectangular carboy" as well -- different manufacturers may use other names.

Comment: @JacobS ah, that returns more consistent results when googling. I'll add that to my answer, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, now that I know the term "carboy" its easy to find. Sometimes I just don't know what I don't know!

Comment: It is easy to confuse -- "carboy" can also refer to large round jugs with small neck and a cap, often used for water (like the jugs for water-cooler dispensers), the transportation of liquids, or in fermentation (homebrewing).